# Flutter dart replaceAll special character not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I cant get this to work it doesnt replace all the special character and white spaces?

```
String sentence = "!@#$%ˆ&*()<>?:"{} Hello ";
String newSentence = sentence.replaceAll("\\W+","").toLowerCase();
print(newSentence);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
String sentense = '!@resu##me'.replaceAll(new RegExp('\\W+'), '');  
print(sentense);
```

**Output:**

resume

For more reference https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.3/dart-core/String/replaceAll.html

Comment: @phongyewtong: Does it satisfy your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
String sentence = "!@#\$%ˆ&*()<>?:\"{} Hello ";
String newSentence = sentence.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]'),"").toLowerCase();
print(newSentence);
```